# I don't think I understand how makefiles work

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a program that uses openGL and c++ to draw a 3D planet. It works and I use the makefile code below to compile it (which also works), but I now created a new .h and .cpp file that I include in my newPlanet.cpp main program. My question is, how do I add this new .h and .cpp file to this makefile in order to have them compiled with the newPlanet.cpp?

```
VRUI_MAKEDIR := /opt/local/Vrui-2.6/share/make
ifdef DEBUG
VRUI_MAKEDIR := $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/debug
endif

INSTALLDIR := $(shell pwd)


RESOURCEDIR = share/VruiExamplePrograms


include $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/SystemDefinitions
include $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/Packages.System
include $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/Configuration.Vrui
include $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/Packages.Vrui


BININSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/$(EXEDIR)
RESOURCEINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/$(RESOURCEDIR)

PACKAGES = MYVRUI

ALL = $(EXEDIR)/NewPlanet   

.PHONY: all
all: $(ALL)

.PHONY: extraclean
extraclean:

.PHONY: extrasqueakyclean
extrasqueakyclean:


include $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/BasicMakefile


$(EXEDIR)/NewPlanet: $(OBJDIR)/NewPlanet.o
```

Comment: "I don't think I understand how makefiles work" - [Start here.](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/)

Comment: I don't see the rules in your makefile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say without knowing what other files have in them, but a good bet would be this:

```
$(EXEDIR)/NewPlanet: $(OBJDIR)/NewPlanet.o $(OBJDIR)/YourNewFile.o
```

But the answers are in `SystemDefinitions`, `Packages.Vrui`, `BasicMakefiles` and probably -  many other places.

Comment: You, my friend, are a genius. It worked. Thank you